# Concatenate pairs of mp3 files with ffmpeg or cat?

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, cat

I've got a directory of mp3 files, which look a little like this:

```
Blue Elephant part 1.mp3
Blue Elephant part 2.mp3
Tale of Two Cities part 1.mp3
Tale of Two Cities part 2.mp3
Lookism part 1.mp3
Lookism part 2.mp3
```

There's always two parts, and they are named consistently. I want to output:

```
Blue Elephant.mp3
Tale of Two Cities.mp3
Lookism.mp3
```

... so each pair of files is merged. How would I do this with ffmpeg or cat on the command line?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:Blue Elephant part 1.mp3|Blue Elephant part 2.mp3" -i "Blue Elephant part 2.mp3" -acodec copy Blue Elephant.mp3 -map_metadata 0:1
```

Comment: thanks. how would I do this for the whole folder?